# How do I get /users/new to show up on /static/index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two controllers: `Users` and `Static`. `Static/index` is my root index page.

I want the `Users/new` form to be displayed on my index page.

All forms are working, just no idea how to include the `Users` form on `Static/index`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
# static controller
def index
   # your stuff ...
   @user = User.new
end

def create
   # your stuff ...
   @user.create(params[:user])   
end

# static's index view
# your stuff ...
<% form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :name, 'Name' %>:
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   # more fields
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you! I'm coming from php and sometimes I just miss the good-ol <include> :)

Comment: You can include other templates with <%= render :partial => 'my_template' %>